In any cyclic quadrilateral is $\frac{1}{d_1} + \frac{1}{d_2} - \frac{d_1-d_2}{2d_2(d_1+d_2)} \ge \frac{1}{R}$ where $d_1,d_2$ are the diagonals?
I obtained this inequality about cyclic quadrilateral by experimental methods. Can it be proved?
Let $d_1 \ge d_2$ be the two diagonals of a cyclic quadrilateral of circumradius $R$; then,
$$
\frac{1}{d_1} + \frac{1}{d_2} - \frac{d_1-d_2}{2d_2(d_1+d_2)} \ge 
\frac{1}{R}
$$
with equality holding only if $d_1 = d_2 = 2R$.

Your question only concerns the diagonals, not any other lengths, and the diagonals can be varied independently of each other to be anything in $(0,2R]$. So this isn't really a question about geometry, it's just a question about whether an inequality holds for all numbers in that range. Fixing $2R=1$ also makes this easier.

You've just changed the inequality when I was in the middle of writing up a proof

@ZoeAllen This is a stronger form of the same inequality. The previous formulation follows from this one by replacing $d_1+d_2$ with $2R$.

Let $  a  = \frac{d_1}{R} , b = \frac{ d_2 }{R}$, so $ a, b \in [ 0, 2 ] $ with $ a \geq b$.
Rewrite the inequality (via partial fractions) to WTS:
$$ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{2b} \geq 1$$
Clearly, the minimal value is obtained when $a, b$ are as large as possible, so we have the desired inequality:
$$ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{2b} \geq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = 1$$
Equality holds iff $a = b = 2$, or $d_1 = d_2 = 2R$.
